# I need to find a list of all the possible Bonds, angles between atoms in a molecule from a smiles string (or .xyz file)

Tags: python, rdkit

I am trying to develop force fields and in order to do so I need a list of all the possible bonds , angles and dihedral in a molecule from smiles string oe .xyz file.

Is it possible that to do it with RDkit? if so, how?

Comment: pls add what you have already tried to solve !

Comment: I have not found anything that I could try. I went through the documentation for RDKit and there was not a lot of information on if I could use it to carry out my task.

Answer (score 1):

To get angles from a molecule it must have at least 2D coordinates, rdkit has no way of constructing a molecule from an XYZ file but can read SMILES strings.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import rdMolTransforms

# Read molecule from smiles string
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('N1CCNCC1')

# Get all bonds in the molecule
bonds = [(x.GetBeginAtomIdx(), x.GetEndAtomIdx()) for x in mol.GetBonds()]
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0)]

# Compute 2D coordinates
AllChem.Compute2DCoords(mol)
conf = mol.GetConformer()

# Get a torsion angle between atoms 0, 1 & 2
rdMolTransforms.GetAngleDeg(conf, 0, 1, 2)
# 119.99999999999999

# Get a dihedral angle between atoms 0, 1, 2 & 3
rdMolTransforms.GetDihedralDeg(c, 0, 1, 2, 3)
# -0.0  (obviously 0 as the molecule has no 3D coordinates)
```

If required you can [generate 3D coordinates](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html#working-with-3d-molecules) for the molecule, or you can read molecules with 3D coordinates using an SDF file or similar. The software [openbabel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page) can convert XYZ into SDF

Comment: Thanks.. I am trying to define the atom types and hence naming the bond. so as per RDKit documentation                                                   AllChem.EmbedMultipleConfs(mol, numConfs=10)                                   res = AllChem.MMFFOptimizeMoleculeConfs(mol)                                This auto defines the atoms, bonds etc. I am trying to dump it somewhere from where I can get the list.